# Prepopulating HTML form fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

So I've been trying to access elements of $scope.user in an html form. My first thought was to use the {{ user.email }} for example, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've seen this method used in other scenarios but perhaps this isn't the case for MEAN.

I'm populating $scope.user through the query to a mongoDB database:

```
$http.get('/api/users/me').success(function (res) {
        $scope.user = res;
        console.log($scope.user);   // properly prints the logged in user to the console
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log('Error');
        $scope.error = err.message;
        console.log($scope.error);
    });
```

My thought was that using the input element's value attribute could be used to prepopulate the field. For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.email" value="{{ user.email }}">
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: use `ng-model="user.email"` and remove value attribute.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for dismissing your comment at first, this does in fact work. I've looked at ng-model some more and I think since it 'binds' to the value of whatever you declare and since form at first is empty is was forcing the field to remain empty. I'm guessing the only work around to this is to assign form.email to be user.email within my controller before the form is pushed to the database I'm using. Thank you so much for the help